# Python - Weird UnboundLocalError

Tags: python

When I run the following function:

```
def checkChange():
    for user in userLinks:
        url = userLinks[user]
        response = urllib2.urlopen(url)  
        html = response.read()
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "InStockBot.py", line 34, in <module>
    checkChange()
  File "InStockBot.py", line 24, in checkChange
    html = response.read()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'response' referenced before assignment
```

Which makes no sense to me. I have no global var response. I expect it to work as below, normally.

```
>>> url="http://google.com"
>>> response = urllib2.urlopen(url)  
>>> html = response.read()
>>> html
'<!doctype html>
```

Anyone know why I get this error?

Comment: Can you post all of your code?

Comment: Here it is: http://pastebin.com/n04NGRYv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing tabs and spaces.  Looking at the raw code you pasted:

```
'    def checkChange():'
'    \tfor user in userLinks:'
'    \t\turl = userLinks[user]'
'    \t\tresponse = urllib2.urlopen(url)  '
'            html = response.read()'
```

You can see the switch in the last line.  Effectively, this means that the `html = response.read()` line isn't indented as far as you think it is, meaning that if `userLinks` is empty, you'll get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "inde.py", line 10, in <module>
    checkChange()
  File "inde.py", line 5, in checkChange
    html = response.read()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'response' referenced before assignment
```

Run your code using `python -tt yourprogramname.py` to confirm this, and switch to always using four-space tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't indented properly. Change it to this and it'll work (probably not as intended, but it will work):

```
for user in userLinks:
    url = userLinks[user]
    response = urllib2.urlopen(url)  
    html = response.read()

    if userSources[user] != html:
        del userSources[user]
        del userLinks[user]
        api.PostDirectMessage(user,'It appears the page has updated! Your item may be back in stock!')
```

The error occurs because you define `response` in the `for` loop, but if the loop doesn't run (i.e. `userLinks == []`), that variable is never set.